# spark scala RDD[double] IIR filtering (sequential feedback filtering operation)

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I can't find a way to do this in Apache Spark (Scala), basically I have a `RDD[Double]`

```
[1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,...]
```

I want to perform a sequential feedback operation on such `RDD[Double]` with the following operation

```
y(n) = 0.5*y(n-1) + x(n), where y(n) is the output , with y(n) = 0 when n < 0 and x(n) is the input, for n = 0,1,2,3...
```

(this can be exactly implemented in Matlab using the following command `filter(1,[1 -0.5],[1,2,3,2,4])`.

So the expected output will be

```
[1.0000,2.5000,4.2500,4.1250,6.0625,...]
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

1. I looked for `scanLeft` in Scala equivalent for spark `RDD` and got this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2991 which is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9999. It seems Spark is planning to have this feature... I'm not familiar with Spark architecture/roadmap yet...  may some one please help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a job for Spark, it can't be effectively parallelized - every element in output depends on all previoius elements of output (and input).

Process it with simple program, but use Seqence (or Iterator) to only store single element that is currently needed and even huge size of data won't be a problem.